# Find longest string in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm supposed to find the longest string in an array, but can't find what's wrong with my code. Something isn't working when trying to debug in Visual Studio Code it just won't detach. Please help me with what's wrong!

Code:

```
let arr = ["Orebro", "Sundsvall", "Hudriksvall", "Goteborg"];

function long_string(arr){
   let longest="";
   for (let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
      if (arr[i]>longest){
         longest=arr[i];
      }
   } 
   return longest;
}

long_string(arr)
```

Can anyone spot the mistake?

Comment: `arr[i]>longest` should be `arr[i].length>longest.length`

Comment: Compare the `length` property in your `if` condition instead of comparing string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check the length of the item and the stored longest string.

```
if (arr[i].length > longest.length) {
//        ^^^^^^^          ^^^^^^^
```

Just another hint, you could use the first item as start value for `longest` and start iterating from index `1`.

```js
function long_string(arr) {
    let longest = arr[0];
    for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].length > longest.length) {
            longest = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return longest;
}

let arr = ["Orebro", "Sundsvall", "Hudriksvall", "Goteborg"];

console.log(long_string(arr));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `reduce` method for this and check length of current string in each iteration.

```js
let arr = ["Orebro", "Sundsvall", "Hudriksvall", "Goteborg"];
let result = arr.reduce((r, e) => r.length < e.length ? e : r, "");
console.log(result)
```

Comment: This does not explain what is wrong with the original code.

Comment: You can ignore the last parameter `, ""` of `reduce` for initialization

Answer (score 2):

Another way to to it would be sorting and getting the first item

```js
let arr = ["Orebro", "Sundsvall", "Hudriksvall", "Goteborg"];
    
console.log(arr.sort((a,b)=>b.length-a.length)[0])
```

Comment: One critique of this method vs. the reduce example is that it takes longer to sort than to iterate only once over every item. Nevertheless, it is a clever solution.

Comment: @BenSteward You are right. As far I know the reduce method is `O(n)` while this is `O(n log(n))`

Comment: Yep. Still creative though. Can’t resist those one liners.

Comment: Wow, this is way over my knowledge right now!  It was specified in the assignment to not use sort though, still, that was my first try actually. That try wasn't nearly as pretty as this one though.

Comment: @SoX It is just practice and the usage of es6 syntax. For example [this](https://tio.run/##TY49DsIwDIX3nMLKlErQA1BRRtgYGBFCaeuGQhQjJ@2COHtIUEHd/H70@d31pH3LwzOsHXUYo8UAmhm2cJZHxoZJrkCeRtf5SVubxWHseHj85Z4CNsRGXiohJs1gyZmrDzw4kzBfWA2vDM4J@pBcKSvoiVWCAPW5VCxSNZ@lRWfCDWpIvVns/r1NdosKGMPI7me/hWjJebJYWjJqMUblL0WMHw) is your same code in es6 and [this](https://tio.run/##TY7BDoIwEETv/YpNL7SJ8gES8Kg3Dx6NMQVKRZuu2RZ@v7YGiLd9k5nZealZ@Y7GT9g77HWMVgdQRFDDjV9It4R8B/w6ud7PytoM56mn8b3hCYNukQy/V4zNisCiMw8faHQm1YjUtvtp2oeacwl1AzqFRTEgiXQADvmlXE05tJyl1c6EJzSQfAscN98hq7JauZCMdeg8Wl1aNOJvRx4hZYxf) as well

Comment: one is a multiline function and the other one a single line function